LTSPICE setting the load current
First of all, thanks for clicking this post.
This circuit is a +12VDC load switch and a load takes 100mA.

To simulate this circuit, I put a random valued resistor as a load.

But the simulation results show only 100uA from the load.
Any methods to make this circuit load consumes 100mA?

Are you familiar with Ohm's law? R = E/I. The top schematic isn't much of a switch.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I was thinking like that. However, when I put a 120ohm to a load (value determined by Ohm's law). 12VDC output doesn't come out, simulation results show 180mV.
Derive is bellow,
R=V/I = 12VDC/100mA = 120 Ohm

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany Thanks so much, I troubleshooted this issue by modeling a PMOS proper values.

Yes, you should use a specific model for a suitable MOSFET. The default is probably some tiny MOSFET you'd find internally on a chip. Also take care the gate voltage is not too high for the part, which simulation will not detect. All the best.

if you want a specific load current, choose a non-random resistor

@YWS - Hi, This appears to be effectively the same as your previous question. Reposting the same question is not allowed. It is considered noise & can waste the time of site members who duplicate effort on the various questions. Therefore I have closed the previous question as a duplicate of this one (since there is info in comments here). || If you don't get a response to a question, please see this article from the [help]. It does not say to repost the question.

(continued) In your comment above, are you saying that you have solved your own problem by using a realistic MOSFET model? If so, you can self-answer this question with a clear & detailed explanation of the solution (e.g. which MOSFET model did you use, what were the results with that model etc.). Then you can áccept the "best" answer (that could be your own self-answer) which indicates that the question has been solved. (Please also see the [tour] for an overview of how the site works, as rules & etiquette here differ from typical forums.) TY

Why not use a "current source" load ?

@Antonio51 One can do that, but when the switch is 'off' it can cause odd effects, like kilovolts across the MOSFET. A current source plus a diode to ground might be better.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany In LTspice, current source flagged as load would be an option. But that doesn’t fix the main problem which is the issue with the default MOSFET model mentioned above.

@SteKulov Didn't know you could do that. Very nice!  I see you mentioned this almost 5 years ago. The smooth limiting is as I would have expected.
